# IN operator in join predicate

Tags: postgresql, join

I am trying to join 2 tables in Postgresql. Col1 in table1 is of type character varying and col2 in table2 is of type character varying[]

Does anybody know why using the IN operator does not work?

This is the query:

`SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.col1 in t2.col2`

and this is the error:
`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "t2"`

Also, 
`SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.col1 in unnest(t2.col2)`

fails with 
`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "unnest"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you currently have, both sides of the `IN` expression are single values. With `IN`, the right-side would be expected to be an array or multi-valued expression, as opposed to a singular value.

If they really are single values, then what you would want is this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col2;
```

If there really was a list expression for the right-hand side, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1 IN (t2.col2, t2.col3);
```

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

`IN` does not operate on *array*s. Rather, it operates on *row*s. You could try using `ANY` instead, which does operate on *array*s.

The doc describes `IN` as where:

> The right-hand side is a parenthesized list of scalar expressions.

and `ANY` as where:

> The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression, which must yield an
>   array value.

See the [*Postgres* doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html) for more details on `IN` and `ANY`, among others.

Comment: But if t1.col1 is a string and t2.col2 is an array of strings, shouldn't t1.col1 IN t2.col2 be OK? How else would you check to see if string in t1.col1 is contained in array t2.col2? Also, t1.col1 IN unnest(t2.col2) fails with a similar syntax error.